# Entity Framework Correlated Sub-query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, correlated-subquery

I would like to create this using Entity Framework.  A list of new objects containing fields from the parent and fields from the most current child record.  I would write the SQL as a correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT p.PolicyNumber, p.HomeState, pt.RevisionDate, pt.TranStatus
FROM dbo.Policy p
JOIN dbo.PolicyTran pt ON p.Id = pt.Policy_Id
AND pt.RevisionDate = (
    SELECT MAX(mpt.RevisionDate)
    FROM dbo.PolicyTran mpt
    WHERE p.Id = pt.Policy_Id
    )
WHERE p.HomeState = 'NY'
```

The context for Policy has navigation to the list of transactions (PolicyTran).

```
var query = context.Policies.Include(t => t.PolicyTransactions);
```

No matter what I try the Linq is incorrect or the SQL is incorrect.  Time to call in the experts.

Comment: Don't be afraid to use the Entity Framework SQL operations to get you up and running and happy for now: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx.

Comment: There's a bug in your 9 year old SQL ! On line 7, you want to be filtering your inner mpt table, so it should be `WHERE p.Id = mpt.Policy_Id`

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty but I believe this gets you what you wanted.

```
var query = db.Policies
.Where(p => p.HomeState == "NY")
.Join(db.PolicyTrans,
    p => p.Id,
    t => t.Policy_Id,
    (p, t) => new { P = p, T = t.OrderBy(tr => tr.RevisionDate).First() })
.Select(g => new {
    PolicyNumber = g.P.PolicyNumber,
    HomeState = g.P.HomeState,
    TransStatus = g.P.TransStatus,
    RevisionDate = g.T.RevisionDate
});
```

Answer (score -2):

This is one way although 2 separate db hits.  You could prob embed the first statement into the second one but that is more complicated for me right now as I don't have a compiler to hand.

```
var maxRevisionDate = context.PolicyTran.Max(x => x.RevisionDate);

var results = context.Policies.Where(x => x.PolicyTran.RevisionDate == maxRevisionDate 
               && x.HomeState == "NY").Include("PolicyTran")
```

I have made assumptions that your entity names are the SAME as your database tables.  The result of this is an IEnumerable of Policies and their corresponding PolicyTrans.

Comment: Here you are getting the max Revision Date of the whole PolicyTran table but the requirement is getting the PolicyTran with max RevisionDate for each policy. 1 Policy has multiple PolicyTrans

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Ok, another way is to not use include at all.  You get a list of max revision dates grouped by Policy first.  So the result of this is a collection of PolicyTran.  You can then foreach the collection and Load each Policy. The syntax to load a policy is something like context.Entry(yourPolicyTran).Reference("Policy").Load();

Comment: This is the naive, poor-performance solution, so not a very helpful answer; the goal is a subquery in EF, which, this is not.

Comment: This solution isn't even correct, should be removed as an answer.